# Arduino passing char to function

Tags: arduino

I apologize if this is a stupid question (It probably is) but I am having a hard time getting a function to work correctly.

My code as it stands:

```
#define photoPin A0    
char photoCode[] = "L";

void loop(void) {
   analogSensor(photoPin, photoCode);
   delay(5000);
}

void analogSensor(int sensorPin, char* sensorCode) {
   //Poll the Photo Cell and append that to the buffer
   int sensorValue=analogRead(sensorPin);
   Serial.print(sensorCode);
   sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "," + sensorCode + ":%04i", sensorValue);

}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following message:

```
In function 'void analogSensor(int, char*)':
i2c_Sensor:104: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and 'char*' to binary 'operator+'
```

But, if I comment out the sprintf line, it compiles fine, and ever 5 seconds, an "L" prints out on the screen.  Ultimately, I am confused as all get out, and don't know where to turn at this point.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one the formatting got borked :)

I'm afriad you cant concatenate char* with the + operator :) You'd have to call sprintf or strcat :) See your local man pages.

Instead of this:

```
sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "," + sensorCode + ":%04i", sensorValue);
```

Try this:

```
sprintf( buf+strlen(buf), ",%s:%04i", sensorCode, sensorValue );
```